# Upload KML / GML / GeoJson to Geoserver through Rest API

Tags: geoserver, geojson, kml, gml, geoserver-rest-api

What is the best option, if any, to **upload a vector format like GeoJson, and or GML to Geoserver**?

The environment from which to upload will be a **client web-application**, so i cannot use curl. In the backend, i am using a **C#-Proxy** to connect to Geoserver.

Do I have to convert the file to shape (*.shp) first in some way, which i am able to upload via REST, or is there an option to load the data directly?

On the [docs](http://docs.geoserver.org/stable/en/user/rest/api/datastores.html), there is an option for uploading **property files**, but i cannot find any documentation on it and am not shure about how to use that or if it can help solving my problems.

Comment: Perhaps the importer module works for you http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_examples.html. Examples are using curl but GeoServer does not know who is sending the GET/POST/PUT requests so use your favorite method. GeoJSON and GML are not supported as datastores on the server side and they would be slow anyway. I would study the CSV to PostGIS example. Perhaps it could be modified to import  also GeoJSON and GML into PostGIS. Another option could be to upload data into PostGIS with some other tool and use REST for creating new layers into GeoServer.

Comment: If you are using a web client may be WFS-T is more suited to this

Comment: Thank you for the comments! While the database-way seems to be able to cover it as a whole, WFS-T seems to be another fair option. What would be the best way to write transaction queries then? Is there any javascript library for generating WFS-T XML? Writing all these xml code by hand seems to be pretty ugly.

Comment: First question is if you want to create new layers or add data to existing ones. With WFS-T you can't create layers.

Comment: Yes, I need to create a new layer from a KML file. So maybe I can manually add a datastore and featuretype via REST, and then use WFS-T to add data from KML / GeoJSON or similar?

Comment: @hnrch did you ever get a working solution to create a new layer from a KML using the Importer REST API? (asking because I'm having trouble getting it to work)

Comment: @amallard The importer extension helped me out. It has a REST interface , too. http://docs.geoserver.org/latest/en/user/extensions/importer/rest_examples.html

Comment: I have issue with the importer extension. Please help! https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/244920/upload-gml-to-geoserver-as-layer-through-rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As user30184 said, the importer extension has been designed exactly for this job, and will convert the data into the format of the chosen target store (e.g., will import the data into postgis or oracle for you).

WFS-T is more geared towards single feature editing than "mass import" and can only handle GML anyways.

Comment: Thanks! So, I create a database-connected datastore, push my data (gml, kml, shp, csv or whatever) to this datastore via Importer to Geoserver and it will generate the layers, right? Is the Importer automatically creating new tables in the database for me?

Comment: I checked all the details of the Importer API [here](https://github.com/boundlessgeo/geoserver-exts/blob/master/importer/doc/markdown/rest.md#imports) and it seems to be solving all my needs. Thanks again for pointing me in the right direction!

Comment: Hi @hnrch , I am using the geoserver rest api importer to do the same thing. However, when I posted an importer, it returns directory list of my geoserver data directory instead of a description of the importer. Why?

Comment: @zhangjinzhou can you post a new issue for that describing the whole problem and post the link here. thanks.