# Upload GML to Geoserver as Layer through REST

Tags: geoserver, wfs, import, gml

I have to upload a GML file to my geoserver through REST. I tried to use importer but it doesn't work (even manually). More specifically, the importer module never generate tasks automatically for GML. When I use another REST call to generate tasks, it returns max-stack-limit error. Further, I noticed that GML is not in the supporting list of importer extension.

Here is the code I used to create a import event:

```
          var uri = 'http://192.168.0.30:8080/geoserver/rest/imports';
          var data = JSON.stringify({"import": {
                 "targetWorkspace": {
                    "workspace": {
                       "name": "wfsresult"
                    }
                 },
                 "targetStore": {
                    "dataStore": {
                       "name": "WFSSourceResult"
                    }
                 },
                 "data": {
                   "type": "file",
                   "file": "/home/zhangj/geoserverDownload/data/wfsresult/u4f3809a0-56a3-11e7-894d-8dc4d5efd317/result.xml.kml"
                 }
              }});
          Request({
            uri: uri,
            method: 'POST',
            auth: auth,
            headers: {
              'content-type': 'application/json'
            },
            body: data
          }, (err, response, body) => {
            if(err) {
              reply(err);
            } else {
              reply(body);
            }
          });
        }
```

Am I using importer extension correctly?

If importer doesn't fit my situation, what should I use?

I got that wfs transaction may be a good solution. How should I use it?

Comment: Is `/home/zhangj/geoserverDownload/data/wfsresult/u4f3809a0-56a3-11e7-894d-8dc4d5efd317/result.xml.kml` on the geoserver machine? Are the permissions such that the geoserver process (tomcat or however you're running it) can read from that file. Are you actually expecting KML or GML?

Comment: when you say doesn't work, what happens - is there an error message? what about in the GeoServer log file?

Comment: Please also share a sample of the GML.

Comment: @BradHards It is not on the geoserver machine. I thought it works as uploading the file from local machine to geoserver. I expect GML. But in the documentation, it doesn't say GML is supported. So I tried KML

Comment: @iant It always say no file found.

Comment: Does it work if you use curl from the command line

Comment: @iant I got the same result

Comment: Plase share the GML you're trying to upload, so that we can have a look at it. Also, what errors do you get in the logs when using the importer ("does not work" is not helping finding a solution)

Comment: I figured it out using ogr2ogr. It is simpler and has less limitation. Thank you guys!